# Miss empty data

Tags: loops, for-loop, undefined

I am trying to loop over data, but the loop breaks when it finds an undefined, is there a way to skip over it?

```
if (typeof data[i]['infectedByRegion'][14]['deathCount'] != 'undefined') {
let tempObj = {};
tempObj['Date'] = data[i]['lastUpdatedAtApify'];
tempObjNum = Number(data[i]['infectedByRegion'][14]['deathCount']); 
tempObj['Num'] = Number(tempObjNum)
resultData.push(tempObj)
 } 
  else {
      continue
      }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure data[i] or data[i][‘infectedByRegion’] or data[i][‘infectedByRegion’][14] is not undefined? If so you are trying to access data on something that is undefined. What happens if you check each level if it is undefined?

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your response. When I console.log ( console.log(typeof data[i]['infectedByRegion'][14]['deathCount']) .. It loops through 5 times and gives me 5 'numbers'. Then I get the error: 

stockholm.js:88 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'deathCount' of undefined
    at stockholm.js:88

Comment: Fixed! I just needed to remove the 'deathcount' and that found undefined!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure data[i] or data[i][‘infectedByRegion’] or data[i][‘infectedByRegion’][14] is not undefined? If so you are trying to access data on something that is undefined. Try check each to see if it is undefined.